# what pattern to get substring using regexp

Tags: regex

I have following two strings, how can I get the numbers in them?, ie 233100 and 233800

```
QA-Ki-233100
QA-Ki-233800-win-vc8-x86-release
```

This is the pattern I have, but not work.

```
oRegexp.Pattern = "QA-Ki-\--[\Z]"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: which language are you using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
(?<=-)\d+(?=-|$)
```

or simply (in this case),

```
\b\d+\b
```

In `(?<=-)\d+(?=-|$)` we have used positive lookbehind and lookahead to make sure only `-` prepends and either `-` or the end of the line (`$`) appends our desired substring `\d+` (the numbers between those).

In `\b\d+\b`, the `-` and `$` both fell under the category of word boundary `\b` so the regex becomes shorter.

Check: https://regex101.com/r/nL9nR1/1